# Delay parent component render till all the child components render reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading

I am a beginner to react. I am rendering the a component A. This component has 5 more sub components in it. Each of them is requesting an API and loading the information from the api. I want to display a loading symbol, till all the responses are received and rendered. I am really not sure how actually to perform this operation. For example:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: getCookie("Authorization") ? true : false,
    loading: true
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}

render() {
  document.body.style = "background: #fafafa;";
  if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? <Loading /> : ""}
        <Child1 />
        <Child2 />
        <Child3 />
        Welcome Home, user
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // User not logged, error
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
}
```

}

I want to show a loading symbol, till all the child elements are rendered. The present code does not work properly. IS there any way to perform this ?

Comment: You could track how many child components you have, pass a function to the child components and call it over the props if the child is loaded. When all children are loaded you can set `loading` to false. However, make sure you return loading before the `return`. Otherwise it will display the loading animation and the children

Comment: You could try [ref callbacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) but they do not account for any async calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: getCookie("Authorization") ? true : false,
    loading: true,
    childrenLength: 3
    childrenLoaded: 0
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}

onChildLoad = () => { //Using arrow functions instead of binding
  this.setState({childrenLoaded: this.state.childrenLoaded + 1}, () => {
   if(this.state.childrenLoaded === this.state.childrenLength){
     this.setState({loading: false});
   }
 })
}

render() {
  document.body.style = "background: #fafafa;";
  if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading && <Loading />}
              <div>
                <Child1 onChildLoad={this.onChildLoad} loading={this.state.loading}/>
                <Child2 onChildLoad={this.onChildLoad} loading={this.state.loading}/>
                <Child3 onChildLoad={this.onChildLoad} loading={this.state.loading}/>
                Welcome Home, user
              </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // User not logged, error
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
}
}
```

It's probably not the smoothest solution, but it might work

**EDIT**

Assuming you have to load something in your child component, you can do something like this:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        isLoaded: false
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      // Load something here...
      this.setState({isLoaded: true}, () => this.props.onChildLoad());
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {
              // The content of the child will only be displayed if the component is loaded itself and the parent component is fully loaded as well
              (this.state.isLoaded && !this.props.loading) &&
                 <div>
                   Here is your child
                 </div>
             }
          </div>
        );
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is a cool idea thanks for it but in the code sample given below, how actually can I load the child in the background ? I mean, in above example, you are returning `<Loading /> ` initially and where are you triggering the child elements to load so that the method `onChildLoad()` will be called ?

Comment: I didn't know that you had the logic to load something in your children, sorry I could have thought of this :) I updated my answer. Hopefully, you will get the idea. I don't know what else you are doing in your children

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have **flags** in parent component **state** for your child components something like **child1Loaded,child2Loaded,...etc**, have a handler in **parent component** to update this from their `componentDidMount()`.

```
     this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: getCookie("Authorization") ? true : false,
        loading: true,
        child1Loaded:false,
        child2Loaded:false,
        child3Loaded:false,
        child4Loaded:false,
        child5Loaded:false,
      };

      updateLoadedFlagHandler = (childName) =>{
        this.setState({[childName]:true});
      }

      render() {
        document.body.style = "background: #fafafa;";
       if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
       return (
       <div>
        {this.state.loading ? <Loading /> : ""}
        <Child1 loadedUpdateHandler={updateLoadedFlagHandler} childName='child1Loaded'/>
        <Child2 loadedUpdateHandler={updateLoadedFlagHandler} childName='child2Loaded'/>
        <Child3 loadedUpdateHandler={updateLoadedFlagHandler} childName='child3Loaded'/>
        Welcome Home, user
       </div>
    );
  } else {
    // User not logged, error
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
 componentDidMount(){
   this.props.loadedUpdateHandler(this.props.childName);
 }
```

You can check for all these flags to be **true** till then show your loader.

Comment: Doesn't it display the loading symbol along with the components (when the website is partially rendered) ?

Comment: you need to check for all flags to be true and remove the loading image using ternary operator.

Comment: Yep, but in the above case you have rendering the loading symbol along with the child components. So if one component have loaded (after some time), as per the above code, don't it display along with the loading symbol ?